# Ускорение времени компиляции С++ кода при уменьшении включений

Tags: c++, компиляция, gcc

Говорят, что удаление ненужных включений ускоряет сборку проекта. Я решил проверить это на простом примере.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

запускаем с флагом -ftime-report

> TOTAL                 :   0.85             0.42             1.30
>   33358 kB

теперь продублирем 100 раз #include

```
    #include <iostream>
   ...
     #include <iostream>


    int main()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Итог:

> TOTAL                 :   0.87             0.51             1.45
>   33358 kB

Eсли запустить прекомпиляцию gcc -E main.cpp > maon.precom.cpp ,
то мы увидим, что дублирование не включаются. При каких тогда условиях можно почувствовать ускорение? Как же тогда воспроизвести такой сценарий?

Comment: Включите ВСЕ библиотечные файлы. А потом - без них. И сравните...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Повторное включение одного заголовочного файла игнорируется из-за стражей (include guard). Попробуйте включать разные файлы. Особенно разница должна быть заметна при использовании библиотек boost, использующих boost::mpl.